# Swift iOS Screenshot of entire Screen including Split View

Tags: ios, image, swift, screenshot

I have been trying to figure out how to take a Screenshot / Screen Capture of not just the application view, but the complete screen of the device.

The main use case is around using the new multi-tasking features in iOS 9 and take a screen shot of the other app running.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
let theView = view
var screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size

if (NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation) {
   screenSize = CGSizeMake(screenSize.height, screenSize.width)
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenSize, true, 0.0)

theView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(theView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

return image
```

Comment: That sounds like it could possibly be a security violation.

Answer (score 3):

[Press the Home and Sleep/wake buttons at the same time.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200289)

As for doing it programmatically, I think you're out of luck. Apps don't get access to the screen content drawn by other processes. This is presumably by design, as part of the security measures that keep apps out of each other's sandboxes.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I had that feeling, but wanted to reach out to the community.

Comment: I can understand their reasons.  It's a shame though; I'd wanted a way for students to (more) easily send screen shots of their work (in another app) to their teacher.  I know the classroom app can do this remotely, but that requires the teacher to request it.  If a student wants to ask for help, it would be nice to be able to do this.